# Web scraping into an Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

For the American election tomorrow, I would like to be able to look at live results in an Excel file and do some analysis on the voting numbers for the House of Representatives. The numbers I would like to get come from the [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/election-results/florida), where there exists a link `https://www.washingtonpost.com/election-results/STATE_NAME` for all 50 states. The relevant numbers I want to obtain are the **number of votes each Democrat/Republican candidate receives** and the **percent of precincts reporting**. These numbers would go into the spreadsheet, as seen here:

[image]

I would guess that the right way to get the data would be to search the district based on the number (column B) for the percent reporting, and then the name to find the number of votes. However, I don't know how to achieve this in Excel in a way that it will update automatically without me copying and pasting in data.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @ImranMalek The only thing I know how to do is the analysis of the numbers that I obtain. I don't know what I need to do to be able to get to those numbers and would like to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a subscription that gets you past the subscription options page you can use the following (I include commented out lines where I took the page HTML and inserted it into an HTML document on the desktop - this means I didn't risk hitting the free access limit and didn't have to tackle the subscription options page)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.washingtonpost.com/election-results/florida/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.70d691c0a9e2"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        '
        ''What ever you need to do for subscription based. I am assuming you have one and do not need to negotiate free limited access.

        Dim html As HTMLDocument
        'Set html = GetHTMLFileContent("C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.html") '<== I read HTML in from desktop here. 

        Dim districts As Object, districtsCount As Long, arr(), hTable As HTMLTable, i As Long
        Set districts = .document.querySelectorAll(".tiling-results-wrapper #elections-code-root")
        'Set districts = html.querySelectorAll(".tiling-results-wrapper #elections-code-root .wpe-result") '<== When using IE to retrieve webpage
        districtsCount = districts.Length

        Dim tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long, header As Long, headers()
        headers = Array("District#", "Candidates", "Votes", "Pct")
        ReDim arr(1 To 1000, 1 To 4)

        For i = 0 To districts.Length - 1

            Set hTable = districts.item(i)
            header = 1

            For Each tr In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                r = r + 1: c = 2
                If Not header = 1 Then
                    arr(r, 1) = "District " & i + 1
                    For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                        arr(r, c) = Replace$(td.innerText, "â€“", "-")
                        c = c + 1
                    Next
                End If
                header = header + 1
            Next
        Next

        arr = Application.Transpose(arr)
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To 4, 1 To r)
        arr = Application.Transpose(arr)

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        End With

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library
2. Microsoft Internet Controls

---

**Sample output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing a solution. I forgot to specify in my original question, but I'm working on Chrome on a Mac and do not have IE. How could I open the page that way?

Comment: You can’t I’m afraid. You will need to use something like python.

Comment: Not sure whether Mac supports python add-ins you might be able to use.

Comment: I was actually able to get to a machine that runs IE and am trying to work this now. I'm being told that some types such as `InternetExplorer` and `HTMLTable` are undefined user types. Am I trying to run the script incorrectly?

Comment: Means you haven't added references via VBE > Tools > References then add Microsoft HTML Object Library and Microsoft Internet Controls.

Comment: I haven't be able to test that pct will output correctly when real values go in so that will be something to watch for.